# How to deal with gmail App password using Javax Mail

Tags: java, email, gmail

My Java Windows app needs to send email and allow the user to specify his/her email account credentials: host, port, username, password. It works when I use my credentials for an account at my hosting service, but not so well when using a Gmail account, as my prospective users might want to do. The problem is Gmail insists on an "App password." So, I follow the Google instructions and create a 16-character App password which Google says has to be used *one time only*. However, I find that the App password MUST be used for subsequent runs.

Here's a sample program that demonstrates the problem. It will fail if I use that actual password for the Gmail account. It will work after I've created an App/device specific password (16 characters) and used it as the password, as it should. But, I have to use that 16-character password thereafter as well. What am I missing?

```
public class SendEmailTLS {
```

// Example 1 from https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    final String username = "me123@gmail.com";
    final String password = "mypassword";

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("me123@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("you456@hotmail.com")
        );
        message.setSubject("Testing Gmail TLS");
        message.setText("Dear sir,"
                + "\n\n I'm testing TLS,using port 587");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I want to add that I'm now suspecting that what I'm seeing is the way it's supposed to work. I had been thinking the 16-char App specific pw was a "Salt" kind of thing to protect the Gmail server. I have now read that it's really just an alternative password for my Gmail account. If anyone can confirm or deny this new perspective, I would be grateful.

Comment: gmail uses `oauth` protocol, I think, try to look into that

Comment: Thanks, Ossama. Unfortunately, I find that to be a bit over my head.